Is this observation about calculus correct?
As the tangent line traverses a function, it rotates clockwise or counterclockwise, at varying velocity.
This rotation/velocity, which I call "yaw", must also be a function, with derivatives.

Yes, it is connected to the second derivative. In fact, you are rediscovering the notion of curvature : in a point of high curvature (think to a road with violent bends), the angle made by the tangent varies quickly.Formula : $f''/(1+f'^2)^{(3/2)}$

What is missing here is a definition of what we mean by "velocity" when we say "as the tangent line traverses a function." I assume by "tangent line traverses" you actually mean "tangent point traverses," but the question is, how fast is the traversal? Is it at a constant rate of $dx/dt$, a constant speed along the curve of the function's graph, or some other rate? Two different formulas have been posted so far, one for each of the first two speeds.

It is far more complex than I realized!

For instance, why isn't the second derivative and the angular velocity the same?

Instead there is (1 + (f')^2) in the denominator. As the tangent line rotates velocity increases, or decreases, and this would seem to indicate something like "instantaneous rate of acceleration", if such a thing exists. But why does it have to be more complex than that?

Yes, I was thinking of a tangent point, at velocity dx/dt.

Yes, you can find a simple relationship between the rate of rotation of a tangent line to a function $f$ and the function's derivatives.
Suppose the angle the tangent line makes with the horizontal at a point $x$ is $\theta(x).$ The derivative of the function and $\theta$ are related by $$\tan \theta(x) = f'(x).$$
Now take derivatives of this relationship if you want to find, say, $\theta'(x):$
$$ \sec^2\theta(x) \theta'(x) = f''(x). $$
$\sec^2\theta(x)$ can be related to $f'$ by $$\sec^2\theta(x) = 1+ \left[ f'(x)\right]^2,$$ so the rate of rotation $\theta'(x)$ is
$$ \theta'(x) = \frac{f''(x)}{1+\left[f'(x)\right]^2}. $$

I see, now it is clear.

Thanks for all of  the comments, very much appreciated.

Your angle is already represented by the 1st derivative because it's already a tangent
$$
\tan \theta=f'( x)
$$
So to get the angle in radians:
$$
\theta =\arctan f'( x)
$$
And finally if we differentiate that we get the angular velocity. Armed with the derivative  $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan x=\frac{1}{1+x^{2}}$ and the Chain Rule:
$$
\theta '=\frac{d}{dx}(\arctan f'( x)) =\frac{1}{1+ [f'(x)]^{2}}f''( x)
$$
Which is the same as what Liam Nor Lear arrived at.

Very clear, thanks.
